# jquery: How to remove dialog for window size greater than 480px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a responsive website, I have to create a popup for smaller device,but for desktop size the content has to be visible (not inside the popup). I am trying not to repeat the content twice. Is there a way to achieve this without the content repeat?

If anyone has done the similar work, could you please give me hint. How to do?

I am working on jsfiddle and will update the link once ready.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)